# "Cannot Import dll" when importing C# DLL in Inno Setup

Tags: c#, .net, inno-setup, pascalscript

I know that this question has answer, but he does not help me. I saw articles: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435282/inno-setup-failing-to-import-dll) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776847/returning-a-string-from-a-c-sharp-dll-with-unmanaged-exports-to-inno-setup-scrip), but I have problem. My code:

C#:

```csharp
[DllExport("ServerOfDataBases", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static int ServerOfDataBases(
  string server, string user, string password,
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] out string strout)
{
  string resultStr = String.Empty;
  // ...
  strout = resultStr;
  return 0; 
}
```

Inno Setup:

```pascal
[Files] 
Source: "GetDataBases.dll"; Flags: dontcopy 

[Code] 
function ServerOfDataBases(server, user, password: string; out strout: WideString): Integer; 
  external 'ServerOfDataBases@files:GetDataBases.dll stdcall';
```

I get this error

> Cannot Import dll:C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Temp\is-ECJ5V.tmp\GetDataBases.dll

Thank you for any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me, if I follow all the instructions from my answer to:
[Calling .NET DLL in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8487925/850848#42711143)

So I would guess, that you didn't set the *Platform target* of your .NET/C# project to *x86*.

---

For more about returning strings from DLL, see:
[Returning a string from a C# DLL with Unmanaged Exports to Inno Setup script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20776847/850848)